# タグを付け替えたい [office] → [ms-office]

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの付け替えの提案

[office](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office) というタグができていたのに気付きました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office

しかし、単に「office」というだけでは MS Office 以外にも WPS Office などがあり、質問内容を有効に絞り込めているように思えません。

英語版 Stack Overflow にならって [ms-office](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office) に付け替えたいです。如何でしょうか。
質問に投票頂ければと思います。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office

Comment: +1 LibreOffice 等もあるので、分類を目的とするなら `ms-office` にした方が分かりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[office](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office) から [ms-office](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office) へのタグの付け替えを行いました。